# Recently installed ubuntu 14.04, and having issues with connecting to a wired connection

Tags: 14.04, networking

I've been trying to fix my problem through other solutions in other questions, but it's not been working. I'm kind of a linux noob, but i am aware that my system is recognizing the connection, but for some reason is not able to connect. Whenever my system boots up, it tries to connect, but then fails, and continues to keep trying. I did not have this problem on windows previously. I'm worried it could be a driver issue, but not sure.

Some outputs:

sudo ethtool eth0:

```
Settings for eth0:
        Supported ports: [ TP MII ]
        Supported link modes:   10baseT/Half10baseT/Full
                                100baseT/Half100 baseT/Full
                                1000baseT/Half1000 baseT/Full
        Supported pause frame use: No
        Supports auto-negotiation: Yes
        Advertised link nodes:  10baseT/Half 10baseT/Full
                                100baseT/Half 100baseT/Full
                                1000baseT/Half 1000baseT/Full
        Advertised pause frame use: Symmetric Receive-only
        Advertised auto-negotiation: Yes
        Link partner advertised link modes:  10baseT/Half 10baseT/Full
                                             100baseT/Half 100baseT/Full
                                             1000baseT/Half 1000baseT/Full
        Link partner advertised pause frame use: Symmetric Receive-only
        Link partner advertised auto-negotiation: Yes
        Speed: 1000Mb/s
        Duplex: Full
        Port: MII
        PHYAD: 0
        Transceiver: internal
        Auto-negotiation: on
        Supports Wake-on: pumbg
        Wake-on: g
        Current message level: 0x00000033 (51)
                               drv probe ifdown ifup
        Link detected: yes
```

sudo lshw -C network:

```
*-network
     description: Ethernet interface
     product: RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
     vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
     physical id: 0
     bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0
     logical name: eth0
     version: 06
     serial: fc:aa:14:0e:87:13
     size: 1Gbit/s
     capacity: 1Gbit/s
     width: 64 bits
     clock: 33MHZ
     capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix vpd bus_master cap_list ethernet             physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
     configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 driverversion=2.3LK-NAPI duplex=full firmware=rtl8168e-3_0.0.4 03/27/12 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes port=MII speed=1Gbit/s
     resources: irq:29 ioport:d000(size=256) memory:fe100000-fe100fff memory:d2100000-d2103fff
```

ifconfig:

```
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet HWaddr fc:aa:14:0e:87:13
          inet6 addr: fe80::feaa:14ff:fe0e:8713/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:96 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:47 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
          RX bytes:26016 (26.0 KB) TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:468 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:468 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0
          RX bytes:58813 (58.8 KB)  TX bytes:58813 (58.8 KB)
```

route:

```
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
```

nmcli dev list iface eth0:

```
GENERAL.DEVICE:                        eth0
GENERAL.TYPE:                          802-3-ethernet
GENERAL.VENDOR:                        Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
GENERAL.PRODUCT:                       Motherboard
GENERAL.DRIVER:                        r8169
GENERAL.DRIVER-VERSION:                2.3LK-NAPI
GENERAL.FIRMWARE-VERSION:
GENERAL.HWADDR:                        FC:AA:14:0E:87:13
GENERAL.STATE:                         70 (connecting (getting IP configuration))
GENERAL.REASON:                        0 (No reason given)
GENERAL.UDI:                           /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:09.0/0000:03:00.0/net/eth0
GENERAL.IP-IFACE:                      eth0
GENERAL.NM-MANAGED:                    yes
GENERAL.AUTOCONNECT:                   yes
GENERAL.FIRMWARE-MISSING:              no
GENERAL.CONNECTION:                    /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/ActiveConnection/15
CAPABILITIES.CARRIER-DETECT:           yes
CAPABILITIES.SPEED:                    100 Mb/s
CONNECTIONS.AVAILABLE-CONNECTION-PATHS:/org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Settings/{0}
CONNECTIONS.AVAILABLE-CONNECTIONS[1]:  a9a951e0-8515-4c1a-af4e-5115e127d753 | Ethernet connection 1
WIRED-PROPERTIES.Carrier:              on
```

lspci -knn | grep Eth -A2:

```
03:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller [10ec:8168] (rev 06)
Subsystem: Gigabyte Technology Co., Ltd Motherboard [1458:e000]
Kernel driver in use: r8169
```

And also the kernel version is 3.19.0-25

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu!  **;-)** what does `sudo ethtool --change eth0 speed 10 duplex half autoneg off` do?

`

Comment: thank you, and although the command didn't help me connect, it changed size to 10Mbit/s, duplex to half, and autoneg to off, predictabely

Comment: Some router/NIC combos have trouble with auto-negotiation... So it wasn't totally out of the blue why I asked...  **;-)**  Do you get an IP address???  The exact problem you have is unclear to me...

Comment: i'm not getting an ip address, though under system settings, in network, it recognizes the wired connection, gives a mac address, but isn't able to connect

Comment: can you add the output of `route` too?

Comment: sorry, just woke up, about to do that now

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Eth -A2` terminal command.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most likely you will need to install another Ethernet driver. Connect to internet some other way and run in terminal

```
sudo apt-get install r8168-dkms
```

Comment: this specific command didn't work, but downloading r8168 drivers and following the readme file fixed my problem, thank you so much :D